# How to mount both sc1 volume on Amazon EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My current 500GB Amazon EBS Cold HDD (sc1) volumes in /dev/sdf is full.  Following the tutorial here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html#migrate-data-larger-volume), I successfully got a 1.5 TB SC1,  mounted in /dev/xvda and attached it to the instance.  Please note that the 500 GB sc1 (/dev/sdf) is also attached to the instance.

Sadly, when I turned on the instance, I only see this new 1.5 TB SC1 in /dev/xvda, but not the old 500 GB SC1 in /dev/sdf and the corresponding data.  When I do df -h:

```
 df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvdg1      1.5T   34G  1.5T   3% /
devtmpfs        7.9G   76K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

If I turned off the instance, detached the 1.5 TB SC1 (/dev/xvda) from the instance, kept the attached 500 GB TB SC1 (/dev/sdf) to the instance, and finally restarted the instance, I will see the 500 GB TB SC1 (/dev/sdf) and its data in it again.

```
 df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdf        500G   492G  8G   99% /
devtmpfs        7.9G   76K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Is there any way that we can mount both of these 2 volumes and see/transfer data between these 2 volumes in the same instance?  Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks.

#

Respond to the comment:

The following is the result of "lsblk" when both 500GB and 1.5GB SC1 are attached.

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part
xvdf    202:80   0  500G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0  500G  0 part
xvdg    202:96   0  1.5T  0 disk
└─xvdg1 202:97   0  1.5T  0 part /
```

The following is the content in "/etc/fstab" when both 500GB and 1.5GB SC1 are attached.

```
LABEL=/     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0   0
sysfs       /sys        sysfs   defaults        0   0
proc        /proc       proc    defaults        0   0
```

extra comments:

UUID results

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Oct 19 08:54 43c07df6-e944-4b25-8fd1-5ff848b584b2 -> ../../xvdg1
```

**#2016-10-21-update**

After trying the following

```
uuidgen
tune2fs /dev/xvdf1 -U <the uuid generated before>
```

making sure both volumes are attached to the instance, restarting the instance, only the 500 GB volume show up.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvdg1      493G  473G   20G  96% /
devtmpfs        7.9G   76K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm

lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part
xvdf    202:80   0  500G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0  500G  0 part /
xvdg    202:96   0  1.5T  0 disk
└─xvdg1 202:97   0  1.5T  0 part /

ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Oct 20 20:48 43c07df6-e944-4b25-8fd1-5ff848b584b2 -> ../../xvdg1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Oct 20 20:48 a0161cdc-2c25-4d18-9f01-a75c6df54ccd -> ../../xvdf1
```

Also "sudo mount /dev/xvdg1" doesn't help as well.   Could you enlighten?  Thanks!

Comment: can you list the available disk and their mount points running `lsblk` when both volumes are attached to the instance ?

Comment: It's not clear how you managed to boot an instance from an sc1 volume attached as /dev/xvda at all.  According to the docs [`sc1` volumes cannot be a boot volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html), nor can `st1`, and your output capture is showing attachments other than xvda.

Comment: I think @FrédéricHenri is on the correct path, and the contents of `/etc/fstab` may also be helpful.  The volumes are attached, but the system will only mount one of them at boot, if mounting by ext2 (compatible) label or uuid... they're clones, so their labels and uuids will be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone's comment.   To @FrédéricHenri & Michael - sqlbot, the lsblk and /etc/fstab results are added in the post.

Comment: I think @Michael-sqlbot had good point and disk could be clone - run with the following arguments `lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,UUID,MOUNTPOINT` will show the UUID of the 2 disks, if they're clone they can't be mount at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2 disk are cloned and have the same UUID they cannot be mounted at the same time and system while booting will mount the first partition it finds.

## Generate a new UUID for your disk

```
uuidgen
```

Running this will give you a new UUID - as the name implies it will be unique

## Apply the new UUID on your disk

In your case `xvdf` is not mounted so you can change its UUID

```
tune2fs /dev/xvdf1 -U <the uuid generated before>
```

## Change your mount point

Its getting better, however as they were clone both disk have the same mount point and that is not possible. you need to update your File System Table.

1. create a new folder which will be your mount point

   ```
   mkdir /new_drive
   ```
2. mount the drive to your new mount point

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/xvdg1 /new_drive
   ```
3. Update `/etc/fstab` so it will be mounted correctly on next reboot

Update the line about `/dev/xvdg1` drive , you have something like

```
/dev/xvdg1  /  ext4  ........
```

Change the 2nd column

```
/dev/xvdg1  /new_drive  ext4  ........
```

All your data from the 1.5 TB are accessible in `/new_drive`. You can verify the file is correct by running `mount -a`

Please adapt this procedure if you want to change the folder name or if you want to keep the 1.5 TB as root mount point and change the 500 GB drive.

Comment: *"system while booting will mount the first partition it finds"* I'm not sure about it being the "first" partition (filesystem, technically, of course).  I've made this error and found it mounted the *last* one.  I don't know what the defined behavior is, but of course you are correct that it certainly will not mount more than one in this case.

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot actually I've never investigated (I think I had a case once and it was not with AWS) which one was picked up. it could be a good question for superuser site

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri.   Just double check:  by renaming UUID: 1. we don't need to shut down the instance 2. we won't lost the data inside the disk/volumne?

Comment: You'll not loose data but I am not sure if you can mount the volume without restart you'll need to do it once though

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri.  I just include "ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid" in the post. So now we can only see the UUID of 1.5 TB /dev/xvdg1 but not the UUID 500GB  of  /dev/xvdf1.  I guess it is because they share the same UUID like you said?

Comment: did you generate and associate new UUID as mentionned in my post ?

Comment: Not yet.  Going to try it in a few minutes

Comment: Hi @FrédéricHenri, just run it and hit another error message.  Could you enlighten?  Thanks!

Comment: sorry it should be `tune2fs /dev/xvdf1 -U <the_uuid>`

Comment: Great!  Now tune2fs /dev/xvdf1 -U <the_uuid> doesn't return any error message, but df -h still don't return the 500GB volume.  I guess I need to restart the instance to see if the 500GB volume is mounted? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri.  Please see the update.  Thanks!

Comment: make any update in your original post and do not reply within the answer so anyone can follow what you attempt

Comment: Thanks, @FrédéricHenri  I just update the new question in the original post.

Comment: ok you cannot have 2 partitions pointing to the same mount point. You need to update your fstab, I've updated my post

Comment: Thanks!  It is working now! However, now the new drive has another HOME/user directory and could cause a lot of confusion.  What are the usual ways to mount multiple volumes on an Amazon instances?